# How to avoid code repetition of adding user id to each and every command object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am building an API with Net Core using CQRS.
For all WRITE operations I have to add `userId` to the command.
The most convenient way of creating commands is to create them from the request body, however userId is not present in the body but in the context (injected during authentication).

I wish I could do that in the middleware so they could be parsed into command but it's not that clean solution to me.

I can create static factory method for each and every command like `FromDTO` which will accept appropriate DTO and userId but it will look exactly the same: assign same fields from dto to command and set userId from the parameter.

How can I solve it with some generic helper created once and used across all controllers with any command?

Comment: Are your POCOs immutable? If not, then you can define an interface `IUserCommand` which declares a mutable `UserId` property and use a single common method to set that `UserId` property from the current request context. If your POCOs are immutable then you'll need to be more creative (e.g. forcing a mutated field via reflection).

Comment: My commands are immutable ...

Comment: How are the command POCOs (class definitions) generated? If they're generated by other tooling (e.g. T4), then modifying that to add the `userId` parameter should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You said your command objects are immutable POCOs. For this I recommend using T4 to generate your factory methods using a request-scoped injectable controller.

If your command POCOs can be generated using T4, then I'd use that to also generate this proposed `ICommandPocoFactoryService` - but you could even do a better job with a Roslyn extension that would use the Roslyn APIs to examine the structure of your POCOs and automatically generate factory methods for it.

Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Roslyn's APIs yet (I have a long list of cool stuff I want to try with it, though!), but here's how the completed/rendered service would look:

```
interface ICommandPocoFactoryService
{
    CommandFoo CreateFoo( String x, Int32 y );

    CommandBar CreateBar( String x, Int32 y );

    CommandBaz CreateBaz( String x, Int32 y );
}

// Register in DI as a Request-Scoped service.
class DefaultCommandPocoFactoryService : ICommandPocoFactoryService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor hca;

    public DefaultCommandPocoFactoryService(
         IHttpContextAccessor hca
    )
    {
        this.hca = hca;
    }

    private MyUserInfo GetMyUserInfo() => this.hca.HttpContext.GetUserInfoFromHttpContextEtc();

    public CommandFoo CreateFoo( String x, Int32 y )
    {
        return new CommandFoo(
            x: x,
            y: y,
            userId: this.GetMyUserInfo().UserId
        );
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommandPocoFactoryService cmdFactory;

    public MyController( ICommandPocoFactoryService cmdFactory )
    {
        this.cmdFactory = cmdFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
    {
        CommandFoo cmd = this.cmdFactory.CreateFoo( x: "x", y: 123 );

        Assert.True( cmd.UserId != default );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nkosi Ah, I didn't know that. I wrote my own `IHttpContextAccessor` for WebForms DI ( https://github.com/Jehoel/AspNetDependencyInjection ) which does allow `HttpContext` to be accessed (because a request-scoped object is created in the context of a request, so a `HttpContext` should be available). I assumed ASP.NET Core's works the same way, my mistake. Thank you for letting me know, I'll update my answer now.

Comment: @Nkosi To confirm, you're saying that `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` returns `null` from an injected service's constructor, even when used for a request-scoped service? That seems... dumb because it means a service's constructor cannot fully initialize itself (e.g. by populating `readonly` state from the `HttpContext`).

Comment: @Nkosi @Dai- IHttpContextAccessor can be injected in the constructor. You need to add that in the configuration `services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` and namespace is `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`

Comment: To be clear. the accessor can be injected into the constructor, no problem. Accessing the HttpContext in the constructor will not have the effect you expected,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components

Comment: @Karthikk there is also `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` extension available.

Comment: @Nkosi I know that `IHttpContextAccessor` has to be added to the DI container and injected (that's what my answer demonstrates, after all), but I can't find anything on learn.microsoft.com that says that an instance of `IHttpContextAccessor`'s `HttpContext` property will return `null`, such as being used inside a constructor.

Comment: @Dai Everything (dependencies) has to be realized before the HttpContext is created and the services container assign to the HttpContext.

Comment: @Nkosi Ah - curious. I'm not sure I like that design - I wish they could have come up with separate context classes (one for the real HTTP context, independent of dependencies and services) and one after - but isn't that what the `ActionContext` is for?

Comment: How can I get that generated?